# promote replica to primary with cluster mode enabled

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

is there a way to promote a replica node to primary with cluster mode enabled? I have [googled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.PromoteReplica.html) but only found solution with cluster mode disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Is not usually recommended to promote a certain replica to primary, since Elasticache already monitor the cluster and perform the necessary failover operations in case of bad cluster status (so no manual intervention is needed).

There is the possibility to invoke the failover API as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_TestFailover.html. You will be able to choose the shard (called node group in the API) where to
perform the failover, but not which replica will become primary. Also this is a limited API call (can be invoked limited number of time) and is designed only for testing purposes

```
aws elasticache test-failover --region <region> \
--replication-group-id <value> \
--node-group-id <value>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send [CLUSTER FAILOVER](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-failover/) command to the replica to promote it to be a new master. However, you must ensure that the replica has already been known by majority of the masters in the cluster.

Check the doc on [manually failover](https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/#manual-failover) for detail.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm new to Redis and we are using ElastiCache redis in our company, I'm wondering if we can use those redis commands directly in this case or we can rely on the commands provided by AWS?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ElasticCache. However, ElasticCache should be compatible with Redis. You can try these commands with in test environment before applying it to production.